# Defining a template specialization in an anonymous namespace (and compile error C2888)

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, template-specialization

**Nutshell version:** Why can't I define a template specialization (of a std-lib type) that's only useful in the current compilation unit in an anonymous namespace inside that compilation unit / cpp file?

**Longer version:**

I have a type that's only a quick helper inside one cpp file, let's call it `struct Helper`. Because it's only used in that compilation unit, it's declared and defined in an anonymous namespace inside the cpp.

Because I want an `std::unordered_set<Helper>`, I have to specialize `std::hash`. When I now try to define it inside the same anonymous namespace, I get a `C2888 'std::hash<'anonymous-namespace'::Helper>': symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'anonymous-namespace'`. Why is that?

I tried adding a `using namespace std` and similar things inside the AN, too, but to no avail.

```
/* This doesn't work */

namespace
{
    struct Helper
    {
        int member1;
        bool member2;
    };

    using namespace std;
    template<>
    struct std::hash<Helper>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Helper& helper) const
        {
            return 12345; /* how it's really generated is irrelevant here */
        }
    };
}
```

Of course, I can just put the specialization outside the AN, and it works. I just want to understand why it *doesn't* while it's inside it!

```
/* This works, but why doesn't the other? */

namespace
{
    struct Helper
    {
        int member1;
        bool member2;
    };
}

template<>
struct std::hash<Helper>
{
    size_t operator()(const Helper& helper) const
    {
        return 12345; /* how it's really generated is irrelevant here */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symbol belonging to namespace `std` must be defined in a namespace that encloses `std` which means that you'll have to define it in the global namespace.

Here's an example from [C2888](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2888):

```
namespace M {
   namespace N {
      void f1();
      void f2();
   }

   void N::f1() {}   // OK: namspace M encloses N
}

namespace O {
   void M::N::f2() {}   // C2888 namespace O does not enclose M
}
```

[`[temp.expl.spec/9]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#9) from the C++20 draft:

> A template explicit specialization is in the scope of the namespace in which the template was defined. [ Example:
>
> ```
> namespace N {
>   template<class T> class X { /* ... */ };
>   template<class T> class Y { /* ... */ };
>
>   template<>
>   class X<int> { /* ... */ };     // OK: specialization in same namespace
>
>   template<>
>   class Y<double>;                // forward-declare intent to specialize for double
> }
>
> template<>
> class N::Y<double> { /* ... */ }; // OK: specialization in enclosing namespace
>
> template<>
> class N::Y<short> { /* ... */ };  // OK: specialization in enclosing namespace
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: OK—good to know! But could you explain a little about *why*, or point me to (at least roughly) the place in the cpp standard where this is stated and (hopefully!) explained? It's not that I doubt you, I would just like to understand the reasoning for it.

Comment: @JohannStudanski Will try to find it in the standard, but I'm not that good at searching in it so it may take time. Could be this: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#9

Comment: Thank you! And if you need to search through it yourself, don't worry, I don't want to foist off that work on you. If you had known from memory where about it was (maybe that one you posted) that's awesome, but otherwise I can happily dig through it myself, too.

Comment: @JohannStudanski Ok, cool. Otherwise, tag the question [tag:language-lawyer] and people eating the standard for breakfast will show up :-)